# is it possible to trim my sed in easier way to get the output?

Tags: regex, sed

In one of my use case, required to trim the needed prefix by using below sed command. just curious to know is there any way to reduce the sed command (i mean simpler way instead of having long trim :) )

Actual content:

```
example1-m.uk.db.com
```

Required output:

```
example1
```

My sed command:

```
echo example1-m.uk.db.com | sed 's/[A-Z]*\-[a-z]\.[a-z]*[0-9]*\.[a-z]*[0-9]*\.[a-z]*//'
```

This gives me as output:

```
example1
```

Thank you.

Cheers , Velu

Comment: `sed 's/-.*//'`? If you need to remove all after the first `-` it will work. A similar solution: `awk -F'-' '{print $1}'`. What are your actual requirements? If we suggest something too simplified, it won't work with other strings you might have.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew super, thank you very much. :) ah got that awk , cheers. my requirement is simple with my use case just extract the output and refer this on other invoking script. executed successfully with my sed command, however your suggestion fits easier and quick. thanks again.